# How do I run code after returned function subscription?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code that looks like this:

```
foo(){
   return this.service.asyncFunction();
}

//in another function:

this.foo().subscribe(() => { some_code });
```

Is it possible to refactor the foo function too look like this:

```
foo(){
   return this.service.asyncFunction().subscribe();
}
```

But still be able to run some_code after the subscription?

Comment: Yes. Try passing a callback to `foo` and passing that to `subscribe`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to subscribe inside `foo()` and still be able to send the observable you can do this

```
foo(){
   const myObs = this.service.asyncFunction();
   myObs.subscribe();
   return myObs;
}
```

Somewhere else in the code, you can do this

```
this.foo().subscribe(() => { some_code });
```

But if you want to use `foo()` and give it some code then you can do this

```
foo(callback){
   this.service.asyncFunction().subscribe(callback);
}
```

And somewhere else in the code, do this

```
for(() => { some code });
```

Comment: If i would call simply this.foo() , whithout .subcribe, will it run properly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by run properly? if your question is: is the equivalent of `this.service.asyncFunction().subscribe();` going to be executed? then the answer is yes

Comment: Yea, from my understanding, if you dont't subscribe to a function it won't run

Comment: No,a function will run, but your asyncFunction(), is probably returning and Observable, if you don't subscribe to an observable, it won't emit